# Return "type" of generic type

Tags: typescript

I have a immutable clone function:

```
import { isObject, toPairs } from 'lodash';

export function cloneDeepWithoutUndefinedKeys<T>(o: T): any {
    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        return o.map((el) => cloneDeepWithoutUndefinedKeys(el));
    } else if (isObject(o)) {
        const c: { [key: string]: any } = {};
        for (const [key, value] of toPairs(o as { [key: string]: any })) {
            if (value === undefined) {
                continue;
            }
            c[key] = cloneDeepWithoutUndefinedKeys(value);
        }
        return c;
    } else {
        return o;
    }
}
```

The return of the function I had to make it `any` but I want it to be `sameTypeOf(T)`. Is this possible?

Comment: What's wrong with using `T` instead of `any`?

Comment: So, sameTypeOf(T) ... is T ?

Comment: Why not use T as return type?

Comment: Ah, I see, it is recursive

Comment: Thanks folks, yes returning T was giving me errors I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use this.

```
export function cloneDeepWithoutUndefinedKeys<T extends any>(o: T): T {
    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        return (o.map((el: any) => cloneDeepWithoutUndefinedKeys(el))) as T; // ADDED
    } else if (isObject(o)) {
        const c: { [key: string]: any } = {};
        for (const [key, value] of toPairs(o)) {
            if (value === undefined) {
                continue;
            }
            c[key] = cloneDeepWithoutUndefinedKeys(value);
        }
        return c as T; // ADDED
    } else {
      return o
    }
}
```

Without the modifications I made, Typescript doubts that the function really returns the same type (`T`), but it is not smart enough to infer that it's really of the same type, basically. So we have to calm it down by manually affirming the type.

Comment: Thank you Nurbol!! Is there a better way to do `toPairs(o as { [key: string]: any })`. I wanted to declar that `o` is an object for sure if it's in this block.

Comment: Also cloneDeepWithoutUndefined also works with non-array non-object, the `else` block, so should we do `<T extends any>`? Thanks very new toTS here.

Comment: You are welcome! I've removed ` as { [key: string]: any }` part. It's redundant, indeed. Regarding the second comment, see the update.

Comment: Yes you should use any in this case. However, I would split this function to smaller ones, each with its own, small concern. This way each function would receive its own type (object/array/any), and you'll have more benefit from using the type system